# Diff of Value Changes inside Reference Changes

Tags: javers

I have a Application entity and a User entity. Theres a one to many relation from application to users, i.e one application can have multiple users.
i update the user and change the application assigned to him. So far i have below:

```
Diff diff = javers.compare(oldUser, newUser);
List<ReferenceChange> referenceChanges = diff.getChangesByType(ReferenceChange.class);
for (ReferenceChange referenceChange : referenceChanges) {
            Object oldRef = referenceChange.getLeftObject().get();
            Object newRef = referenceChange.getRightObject().get();             
            Diff refDiff = javers.compare(oldRef,newRef);               
        }
```

Please find the below result while debugging:
**referenceChanges List:**
ReferenceChange{globalId:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.User/3', property:'application', oldRef:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.Application/7', newRef:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.Application/3'}
**oldRef**
Application [applicationId=7, applicationName=KYC, applicationDesc=DEV_TEST, applicationLaunch=2016-12-31 00:00:00.0, live=false]
**newRef**
Application [applicationId=3, applicationName=KYC, applicationDesc=hellp, applicationLaunch=Sat Mar 12 00:00:00 IST 2016, live=true]

When i pass both objects to javers.compare(oldRef,newRef), it again gives me same result as **referenceChanges**. I thought it should give me Value Changes of each property e.g, applicationDesc, oldVal = DEV_TEST, newVal = hellp.

Am i missing something here? All i want to do is to get the value changes of properties of the Application object which is referenced inside User object.

P.S: If i change `Object oldRef = referenceChange.getLeftObject().get();` to `Object oldRef = referenceChange.getLeftObject();`, i get `JaversException: CLASS_EXTRACTION_ERROR JaVers bootstrap error - Don't know how to extract Class from type 'T'.`

**UPDATE**
Just noted i am not getting ValueChanges while doing 
`Diff refDiff = javers.compare(oldRef,newRef);`
Debug shows follwing changes:

```
Diff:
```

1. NewObject{globalId:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.Application/7'}
2. ObjectRemoved{globalId:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.User/5'}
3. ObjectRemoved{globalId:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.Application/3'}
4. ObjectRemoved{globalId:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.User/6'}
5. ObjectRemoved{globalId:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.User/7'}
6. ReferenceChange{globalId:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.User/3', property:'application', oldRef:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.Application/3', newRef:'com.ds.appmanager.services.domain.Application/7'}

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: All i want to do is to get the value changes of properties of the Application object which is referenced inside User object.

Comment: I don't understand why you are calling compare () reqursively. It's enough to call it once and all objects are compared

Comment: Found an interesting behavior, the compare method seems to work when i do not use hibernate annotations @ManyToOne/@OneToMany.

Comment: Can you look at the code please, The AuditInterceptor class is the one where i am using javers. The entities are in domain package. check the app-manager-services project.
https://github.com/Sarvesh-D/App-Manager.git

Comment: is there runnable and failing test case?